# ML bound conditions

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals

I was wondering under which conditions do the ML bounds apply.

For example I was asked to compute $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx$ using complex analysis. From calculus I know that the primitive function is $\arctan(x)+C$ and that the integral equates to $\pi$.

Then in the complex plane we were given the contour $\Gamma_R$ with $R>1$ being part of the circle $|z| = R$ that lies on top of the real
axis. And that the simply closed and positively oriented contour $C_R$ consists of $\Gamma_R$ and the segment of the real axis $(\Gamma_{R_{2}})$ that lies between $−R$ and $R$.

Then I stated that by means of Cauchy's integral formula that

$$\int_{C_R}\frac{1}{z^2+1}dz=\int_{\Gamma_R}\frac{1}{z^2+1}dz+\int_{\Gamma_{R_{2}}}\frac{1}{z^2+1}dz=\frac{2\pi i}{2i}=\pi$$

Whereafter it follows that

$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{C_R}\frac{1}{z^2+1}dz=\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\Gamma_R}\frac{1}{z^2+1}dz+\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\Gamma_{R_{2}}}\frac{1}{z^2+1}dz=\pi$$

And that by means of an ML bound
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\bigg|\int_{\Gamma_{R}}\frac{1}{z^2+1}dz\bigg|\leq \lim_{R\to\infty}ML=\lim_{R\to\infty}\frac{\pi R}{R^2-1}=0$$
then

$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{C_R}\frac{1}{z^2+1}dz=\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\Gamma_{R_{2}}}\frac{1}{z^2+1}dz=\pi$$

And since on the real axis $R$ is simply $x$

$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{C_R}\frac{1}{z^2+1}dz=\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\Gamma_{R_{2}}}\frac{1}{z^2+1}dz=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx=\pi$$

However when I would apply the ML bound to the entire contour $C_R$ I obtain

$$\bigg|\int_{C_R}\frac{1}{z^2+1}dz\bigg|\leq\frac{R(\pi+2)}{R^2-1}$$

and that taking the limit of $R$ to infinity yields that the absolute value of this limit is smaller than or equal to $0$, isnt this a contradiction (assuming that my steps are correct) of the method applied above. This seemingly tells me that the ML bound cant be applied to any contour.

I was then wondering if anyone could clarify this finding.